# Python pandas: How to slice dataframe using 13 digit timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
              DateTime                   Seq
timestamp
1475504294990,10/03/2016 10:18:14:990000,2123847
1475504446660,10/03/2016 10:20:46:660000,2123908
1475504524410,10/03/2016 10:22:04:410000,2123953
1475504848100,10/03/2016 10:27:28:100000,2124067
1475504940530,10/03/2016 10:29:00:530000,2124126
```

i want to slice this dataframe using a start and end time stamp

```
start = 1475504446660
end = 1475504848100
print df[start:end]
              DateTime                   Seq
timestamp
1475504446660,10/03/2016 10:20:46:660000,2123908
1475504524410,10/03/2016 10:22:04:410000,2123953
1475504848100,10/03/2016 10:27:28:100000,2124067
```

However,I am getting this error:

```
IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type long to integer
```

I tried using df[int(start):int(end)], still getting same error

Answer (score 2):

To slice you have to define the timestamp as the index and use `loc` to perform label indexing (else it is ambiguous between position and label indexing for integer indexes).

```
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
df.loc[start:end]

#                                  DateTime      Seq
# timestamp                                         
# 1475504446660  10/03/2016 10:20:46:660000  2123908
# 1475504524410  10/03/2016 10:22:04:410000  2123953
# 1475504848100  10/03/2016 10:27:28:100000  2124067
```

By default in the case of an `integer` index the indexing is made by position and not by label, see the result in this example.

```
df[0:2] # equivalent to df.iloc[0:2]

#                                  DateTime      Seq
# timestamp                                         
# 1475504294990  10/03/2016 10:18:14:990000  2123847
# 1475504446660  10/03/2016 10:20:46:660000  2123908
```

### Note

If you do not want to define `timestamp` as the index you can use this syntax to obtain the same result.

```
df.query('@start <= timestamp <= @end')

#        timestamp                    DateTime      Seq
# 1  1475504446660  10/03/2016 10:20:46:660000  2123908
# 2  1475504524410  10/03/2016 10:22:04:410000  2123953
# 3  1475504848100  10/03/2016 10:27:28:100000  2124067
```

Comment: No I have not. I will look into it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the start and end timestamps to actual pandas timestamp objects and also convert the index to a timestamp and then select with brackets.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit='ms')
start = pd.to_datetime(1475504446660, unit='ms')
end = pd.to_datetime(1575504848100, unit='ms')
df[start:end]
```

Output

```
                                           DateTime      Seq
timestamp                                                   
2016-10-03 14:20:46.660  10/03/2016 10:20:46:660000  2123908
2016-10-03 14:22:04.410  10/03/2016 10:22:04:410000  2123953
2016-10-03 14:27:28.100  10/03/2016 10:27:28:100000  2124067
```